# How do I convert a Win32 lParam to a C struct?

Tags: c, winapi

Say I have some windows method and a struct:

```
struct SomeStruct{
int foo;
int bar;
int baz;
int bat;
}

SomeMethod(int a,int wParam, int lParam)
{
   SomeStruct s;

   // get lParam into SomeStruct
}
```

How to I get the lParam into a SomeStruct variable? I'm thinking that I need something like this (but feel free to point out my ignorance):

```
SomeMethod(int a, int wParam, int lParam)
{
  SomeStruct *s; //declare struct variable
  s = lParam;    //assign integer value as pointer to struct
  printf("the value of s.foo is %d", s.foo);  //print result
}
```

Comment: Is there a specific method you are working with?  I think your answer will work for most, but some methods are different.

Comment: Your SomeMethod should probably be: `SomeMethod(int a, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)` ... can't recall whether 'int' is always as wide as an LPARAM (aka LONG_PTR), but even if it _is_, any developer coming after you may wonder the same thing, so better to use LPARAM, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, assuming that lParam 'really' contains a pointer to the struct, then you get at it by 'casting':

```
  SomeStruct* s; //declare pointer-to-struct variable
  s = (SomeStruct*) lParam;    //assign integer value as pointer to struct
  printf("the value of s->foo is %d", s->foo);  //print result
```

Comment: Just be ware that it's up to you to make sure it is what you say it is.

Comment: Yeah, it's supposed to be a pointer to that type struct. thanks

Comment: Integers aren't smaller than pointers because he tagged it "Win32", not "Win64"; in any case, lParam ought to be a LONG, not an INT (perhaps he oversimplified it somehow in his OP).

Comment: LParam is in fact an LPARAM, i.e. a LONG_PTR, and thus big enough for a SomeStruct*

Answer (score 1):

lParam and wParam are usually names for variables of the WPARAM and LPARAM types respectively.
WPARAM and LPARAM types of variables are used to declare parameters in SendMessage, PostMessage, WindowProc,DefWindowProc - MS Windows API as well as in the message handlers (frequently but inappropriately called event handlers).
Historicaly, in 16-bit versions of windows, WPARAM was defined as WORD (16-bit) value and LPARAM was defined as LONG; that explains names.
Both parameters are uses as untyped cookies, that carry some information in a message, either value or the address of the entity containing more information that is processed by a message handler.
In 16-bit world, WPARAM was used to carry near address and LPARAM used to carry far address.
WPARAM and LPARAM are types now defined as 32-bit values. In SDKs (Software Developer Kit) in WinDef.h.
WPARAM is defined as UINT in earlier versions of SDK and now as UINT_PTR.
LPARAM stays defined as LONG in earlier versions of SDK and now as LONG_PTR

Answer (score 0):

Just be careful when you cast integers to pointers. On x64 architectures, `int` remains a 32-bit integer, but pointers are 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the correct types, or your code *will* fail on Win64.

```
SomeMethod(int a, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
  SomeStruct *s = (SomeStruct *) lParam;
  printf("the value of s.foo is %d", s.foo);  //print result
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but It's a huge mistake to try to convert integers into pointers. To use an undefined type pointer, just use the *void pointer*. Instead of:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    int foo;
    int bar;
    int baz;
    int bat;
}

SomeMethod(int a, int wParam, int lParam)
{
    SomeStruct *s; //declare struct variable
    s = lParam;    //assign integer value as pointer to struct
    printf("the value of s.foo is %d", s.foo);  //print result
}
```

You might use:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    int foo;
    int bar;
    int baz;
    int bat;
}

SomeMethod(int a, int wParam, void *lParam)
{
    struct SomeStruct *s; //declare struct variable
    s = (struct SomeStruct *)lParam; //assign integer value as pointer to struct
    printf("the value of s.foo is %d", s->foo); //print result
}
```

Where also a concrete pointer to the structure may work:

```
SomeMethod(int a, int wParam, struct SomeStruct *lParam)
{
    printf("the value of s.foo is %d", lParam->foo);  //print result
}
```

Try reading some tip about C, like [C-FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: ...but in some situations in Windows programming, you *need* to use an LPARAM.